# Laravel 5.8: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I have a table called `user_wallet` like this:

[image]

So each `wallet_id` represents a single wallet at `wallets` table:

[image]

Now I'm trying to show some results such as the wallet **name** and wallet **balance** together like this:

```
@php
$us_id = Auth()->user()->usr_id;
$user_wallet = App\UserWallet::where('user_id', $us_id)->get();

foreach($user_wallet as $uw){
    $wallet_info = App\Wallet::find($uw->id);
    foreach($wallet_info as $wf){
        @endphp
        <ul style="list-style:none">
            <li>
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="flexRadioDefault" id="flexRadioDefault1">
                    <label class="form-check-label small mr-3" for="defaultCheck2">
                        {{ $uw->balance }} - {{ wf->name }}
                    </label>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        @php
    }
}
@endphp
```

But I get this error:

Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

And it is referring to this line:

[image]

So what's going wrong out there? How can I solve this issue?

Comment: `1` You have 2 `@php` and 2 `@endphp`.  `2` move your php code to controllers and just print variable results in blades (don't write dirty code)

Comment: `find()` gives you a model instance, not an array. Change it to `App\Wallet::where($uw->id)->get();`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this line : `$wallet_info = App\Wallet::find($uw->id);` gives you 1 object which you can not use in foreach

you can use something like this:

```
App\Wallet::where('id',$uw->id)->get();
```

Comment: I tried it but it does not show anything!

Comment: in this line : $wallet_info = App\Wallet::find($uw->id); what is inside $uw ???
i think you should use $uw->wallet_id

Comment: You were right. I tried `$uv->wallet_id` but still no data appears

Comment: another problem might be here :  Auth()->user()->usr_id;
whats usr_id ?? is it correct? shouldnt it be just id??
take a deep look at your code again from start

Comment: No I store user id as `usr_id` at `users` table

Comment: users table has id itself. no need for another field for that